# Concurrency - Why this deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

OK. I am facing some difficulties in understanding the basics of concurrency. This question is about Deadlock. Please tell me why are both of these threads end in a deadlock.

I took this example from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html) tutorial. And it says,

*"When Deadlock runs, it's extremely likely that both threads will block when they attempt to invoke bowBack. Neither block will ever end, because each thread is waiting for the other to exit bow."*

What I understand from this is that: First, they would wait because when a thread invokes a synchronized method, it automatically acquires the intrinsic lock of the object to which the synchronized method belongs, and continues to own it until the method returns; and meanwhile no other thread can own it.

**1. Now my first question is that the first thread calls zarah.bow(), so the intrinsic lock is associated with zarah. The second thread would call khan.bow() and so that would be a different intrinsic lock (because it is associated with a different object named khan), isn't it?**

**And aren't zarah.bow() and khan.bow() different? Because they belong to two different instances?**

**2. The second question is from the notion of "both" the threads waiting forever. Both the threads will be blocked forever waiting for each other to exit bow. I don't get this.**

```
package Threads;

public class DeadlockModified {
    static class Friend {
        private final String name;
        Friend(String name){
            this.name=name;
        }
        private String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }
        private synchronized void bow(Friend bower){
            System.out.format("%s: %s"+" bowed to me.%n",bower.getName(),name); 
            bower.bowBack(this);
        }
        private synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower){
            System.out.format("%s: %s" + " was nice enough to bow back to me.%n",bower.getName() ,name );
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        final Friend zarah= new Friend("Zarah");
        final Friend khan= new Friend("Khan");
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){zarah.bow(khan);}
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){khan.bow(zarah);}
        }).start();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:-

```
Khan: Zarah bowed to me.
Zarah: Khan bowed to me.
```

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:-**

In this tutorial's section of "Synchronized methods" it was written that,

*"Invoking other objects' methods from synchronized code can create problems that are described in the section on Liveness."*

This is the section on Liveness. I see that another object's method bowBack() is being called from bow(). There are some problems as well- Looking at the output of the program, looks like bowBack() has not been executed by both the threads. But there aren't any more details given.

Comment: Did you take the call to bowBack into account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Thread 1 calls `zarah.bow(khan)`: it acquires the intrinsic lock of the object referenced by `zarah`
- Thread 2 calls `khan.bow(zarah)`: it acquires the intrinsic lock of the object referenced by `khan`
- Thread 1 tries to call `khan.bowBack()`: it needs the intrinsic lock of khan to be able to do that. But this lock is held by Thread 2. So Thread 1 waits until thread 1 releases the lock of `khan`
- Thread 2 tries to call `zarah.bowBack()`: it needs the intrinsic lock of zarahto be able to do that. But this lock is held by Thread 1. So Thread 2 waits until thread 1 releases the lock of `zarah`

Both threads are thus waiting for each other, forever. That's a deadlock.

Comment: Thank you indeed. I just got clear about this concept.

Comment: That's a classic anti-pattern:  Thread A tries to acquire lock 1, and then lock 2 while Thread B tries to acquire lock 2 and then lock 1.  It's always a deadlock waiting to happen.  One fix is to implement a policy that locks are always acquired in a strict order:  If a thread already has lock 2 and it needs lock 1 at the same time, then it must first release lock two, then acquire lock 1, and then re-acquire lock 2.  Slows things down, but avoids the deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

> And aren't zarah.bow() and khan.bow() different?

Yes the calls to `bow()` are executed on different instances but internally they call `bowBack()` on the other instance and that call is synchronized as well.

Example: `zarah.bow()` will synchronize on `zarah` (i.e. the instance it is called on) as well as `bower.bowBack(this);` within the call of `khan.bow(zarah)` because this could also be read as `zarah.bowBack(khan)` (`bower = zarah` and `this = khan` in that context).

> Both the threads will be blocked forever waiting for each other to exit bow.

Without any mechanism to interrupt one of the threads, both will wait for the other to leave the synchronized part and since both are waiting within their own synchronized block, they'll never leave.

A good non-tech example on deadlocks would be the [dining philosophers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem). Each philosopher would be an "instance" of class "Philosopher" and would hold an own intrinsic lock on his fork while waiting for the others to releas their locks on their forks.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that you really understand this, try rewriting the methods using the idiom

```
synchronized(Object){
enter code here
}
```

This acquires the intrinsic lock on the (Object). See if you can replicate the behaviour of deadlock in this idiom. Then rewrite it so that it works.

Doing this will teach you two things:

1. Calling a synchronized method acquires a lock on the object which the method is attached to. So in this case zarah.bow(Khan) acquires a lock on zarah, but not on Khan.
2. If you have a synchronized method which calls other synchronized methods, you must make absolutely sure that it will always acquire all the locks.

On (2), you could, for example, make the code in the bow method:

```
synchronized(bower){
System.out.format("%s: %s"+" bowed to me.%n",bower.getName(),name); 
        bower.bowBack(this);
}
```

which will probably work at least some of the time. This sets up a so called race condition. It will avoid deadlock most of the time since System.out.format is quite a slow method to execute, whereas acquiring a lock is fast. Since it shrinks the gap between acquiring the two locks, it reduces the possibility of deadlock, since the chance for context switching is lessened.

This is, of course, a terrible way to solve the problem. A solution which works here is to create an object, and instead of calling a synchronized method use the synchronized(lock) to acquire the lock on that new object. Then the code will run because the new object's intrinsic lock acts as a proxy for acquiring both locks at once. Create a new empty class:

```
static class proxyLock(){};
```

then rewrite the method bow as:

```
private void bow(proxyLock lock, Friend bower){
synchronized(lock){
    System.out.format("%s: %s"+" bowed to me.%n",bower.getName(),name); 
        bower.bowBack(this);
    }
}
```

The main method gets one new proxy lock that is passed to both threads, and insures that only one thread runs the method at once, as the other thread is blocked until the lock on proxylock is released, which effectively means that the thread is acquiring both locks.

Of course, this idiom has its problem, there is nothing to stop someone else writing a method that doesnt know about proxylock and setting up a deadlock, which is why you should always DOCUMENT YOUR CONCURRENCY PROTOCOLS. Any class designed for concurrency should have a java doc entry that explains how it implements thread safety.

Also, read concurrency in practice. Its the best book by far for Java Concurrency.